# How to use variables along with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I haven't grasped the concept how to use variables, in this situation for example.

Have two tries and nothing works as it should

First

```
var aWidth = { width: "610px" }, 1000

$('#Top1, #Bot1').show().animate(aWidth())
```

Second

```
var aWidth = animate({ width: "610px" }, 1000 )

$('#Top1, #Bot1').show().aWidth;
```

Comment: Yes I shall make a hidden div visible.
`$($(this).attr('href')).show().animating();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the best I can do to rewrite it properly:

**First:**

```
var animation = {
  properties: {width: 610},
  speed: 1000
};

$('#Top1, #Bot1').show().animate(animation.properties, animation.speed);
```

**Second**

```
$.fn.animate_width = function() {
  return this.animate({ width: "610px" }, 1000);
};

$('#Top1, #Bot1').show().animate_width();
```

I'd first learn normal JavaScript and then move on to jQuery. Without fundamental JavaScript concepts, you will be confused very quickly by jQuery's syntax.

Comment: This code did I end up with
` var Speeds = 1000; 
 var queSpeeds = ({queue: false, duration: Speeds}); 
 var aniOpacity = ({opacity: 0.82});
 var aniWidth = {width: 610}; 
 $.fn.animating = function() {
   return this.animate(aniOpacity, queSpeeds).animate(aniWidth, Speeds)};
 $('#Top1, #Bot1').show().animating();`

Comment: It's not a good idea to create new jQuery plugins like `$.fn.animating`. I just did that as an example. I would strongly advise against doing it.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
var aWidth=610;
var aSpeed=1000;

$('#Top1, #Bot1').animate({width:aWidth+"px"},aSpeed);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to have one variable for the animation properties, and another for the speed:

```
var props = { width: "610px" };
var speed = 1000;
$('#Top1, #Bot1').show().animate(props, speed);
```

If you really wanted a single variable for all the animation parameters, you could make use of the Javascript [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) (just invokes a function with parameters defined by an array you pass it, *animationParams* in this case):

```
var animationParams = [ { width: "610px" }, 1000 ];
$('#Top1, #Bot1').show().animate.apply(animationParams);
```